# Is there "Not enough command line parameters exception"?

Tags: c#

What exception should I throw if I wrote a program that expects more than 2  command line parameters and the user gave it an insufficient amount of arguments? I want to use the integrated exception handling.

Comment: Why an exception? Just write the usage of the program, and then give an exit code unequal to 0. You cannot really handle the exception from the calling application anyhow, and since you intended to close the program afterwards, I don't see the need for an exception

Comment: If you expect program to be used by humans it might make sense to print message so that user can provide expected parameters.

Comment: Most command line programs I deal with print the "help" file when either insufficient parameters are given or the parameters don't match what is expected.

Comment: If any I would pick ArgumentException but, indeed why bother?

Comment: Don't down-vote this. It's a good question and a great way to benefit from the experience of the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use an exception.

Indeed, as answered by @Jennifer, `ArgumentException` is the standard exception for invalid arguments. But this isn't quite what it's normally used for, not what other programmers will expect reading your code, and not what users will expect running your program.

`ArgumentException` normally indicates a programmer error, where *you* pass in an invalid argument. It indicates a bug in your code: you should fix the code to either pass in a valid argument, or avoid the call if you know you don't have a valid argument.

In this case, that's not possible. Getting invalid arguments into `Main` is a user error, not a programmer error, and user errors should be handled differently. Throwing an exception makes for a bad user experience: unhandled exceptions crash the program and get Windows to search online for a solution. All that should be done here is to print an error message, and ideally exit with a non-zero status code. There is no exception type that has that effect.

Comment: Agreed. If you would think of your application as a website, throwing the Exception would be a 500 Server Error. If you catch the problem in code as a missing parameter you can ask for further information or return a 4xx client error

Answer (score 1):

[`ArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(loband).aspx) is the standard for invalid arguments.

> The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.